# Boot & Login times increased manyfolds after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

I have been using Ubuntu for more than 8 years now as my daily engine at home. However, after I upgraded recently from 16.04 to 18.04, I have started seeing huge increase in the boot times and then login times as well. From the time I press the power button to boot the computer to the time I see the logged in screen it takes close to 7 minutes. In the earlier versions I had seen boot times to be as low as 30-40 seconds. This increase is unacceptable and causes a lot of problems. In the earlier version (16.04) the overall time taken for the same activity was close to 2 mins.

Can someone please help? I am pasting the output of the systemd-analyze blame command if it helps..

```
administrator@shs:~$ systemd-analyze blame
 1min 6.168s nmbd.service
     51.843s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     32.898s dev-sda5.device
     29.043s systemd-journal-flush.service
     15.212s apt-daily.service
     11.922s mysql.service
      7.681s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      7.568s udisks2.service
      6.789s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.239s networkd-dispatcher.service
      5.849s snapd.service
      4.821s accounts-daemon.service
      4.712s ModemManager.service
      4.662s NetworkManager.service
      3.372s dev-loop0.device
      3.371s dev-loop1.device
      2.029s grub-common.service
      1.940s keyboard-setup.service
      1.784s motd-news.service
      1.528s apparmor.service
      1.515s apport.service
      1.479s avahi-daemon.service
      1.450s gdm.service
      1.393s tlp.service
      1.334s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
      1.330s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.271s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.255s sys-kernel-debug.mount
      1.245s dev-mqueue.mount
      1.227s preload.service
      1.190s dev-hugepages.mount
      1.169s ssh.service

administrator@shs:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2min 14.394s (kernel) + 1min 58.449s (userspace) = 4min 12.844s
graphical.target reached after 1min 57.050s in userspace

administrator@shs:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.
graphical.target @1min 57.050s
└─multi-user.target @1min 57.047s
  └─smbd.service @1min 56.286s +760ms
    └─winbind.service @1min 56.072s +211ms
      └─nmbd.service @49.900s +1min 6.168s
        └─network-online.target @49.897s
          └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @43.107s +6.789s
            └─NetworkManager.service @38.440s +4.662s
              └─dbus.service @38.006s
                └─basic.target @37.972s
                  └─sockets.target @37.972s
                    └─snapd.socket @37.952s +18ms
                      └─sysinit.target @37.923s
                        └─swap.target @37.923s
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6edd976e\x2d0bed\x2d4197\x2da622\x2d387512273b5d.swap @37.813s +99ms
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6edd976e\x2d0bed\x2d4197\x2da622\x2d387512273b5d.device @37.811s
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Edit

Here is the output of free -h and df -h commands:

```
administrator@shs:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2.9G        2.2G         82M        440M        686M        206M
Swap:          2.0G        649M        1.3G
administrator@shs:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           300M  3.4M  296M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        44G   32G  9.9G  77% /
tmpfs           1.5G   20M  1.5G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/loop1      6.0M  6.0M     0 100% /snap/communitheme/124
tmpfs           300M   16K  300M   1% /run/user/113
tmpfs           300M  136K  300M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of 'free -h' and also 'df -h'?  These check memory usage and disk usage respectively.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the output of both the commands. Thanks.